# Maven jenkins build cannot remove folder target-grunt

Tags: maven, jenkins, gruntjs

I have a maven project building on jenkins.

I get the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.2:clean
(default-clean) on project informiam-platform: Failed to delete directory:      
/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/project/target. Reason:
    Unable to delete directory                       
/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/project/target/checkout/pathTo/
target-grunt/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/.bin -> [Help 1]
```

When I log into the machine as the same user jenkin runs on I am able to manually delete the folder without any problem.

Any help would be appreciated, even if you have a method to output exactly why it failed to delete .bin folder?

Comment: What is grunt doing while you delete?  Does it have a watch task?  Showing us your gruntfile may help.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably .bin file is not exposed to maven. You may need to configure maven-clean-plugin to delete .bin file as well. Here is a snippet of the configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <filesets>
        <fileset>
          <directory>${basedir}\target</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.bin</include>
          </includes>
        </fileset>
      </filesets>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```